# trying to create a terminal using jquery.terminal

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-terminal

Hi I am trying to create a [jquery.terminal](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal). I tried to follow this [article](https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288), here it uses the `body tag`, I wish to use only a div for the terminal area not the whole body. Tried accessing the `<div id="myterm"></div>` like

```html
<script>
  $('#myterm').terminal({
    hello: function (name) {
      this.echo('Hello, ' + name + '. Welcome to MyTerm');
    }
  },
  {
    greetings: 'Checkout help !'
  });
</script>
```

But didn't  work !

Comment: Do you get an error in the console about #myterm being an invalid selector? If so then you need to define your div before the script. Or use `$(function() { });` there is a note in the article.

Comment: @jcubic the issue was regarding the cdn's sometimes the js files failed to get downloaded, idk maybe my internet issue or the cdn's delivery system. After I locally downloaded and changed the refrence's to the local one's it started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work.
Try `hello world` on the prompt

```js
$('#myterm').terminal({
    hello: function (name) {
      this.echo('Hello, ' + name + '. Welcome to MyTerm');
    }
  },
  {
    greetings: 'Checkout help !'
  });
```

```css
#myterm {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1pxs solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/2.34.0/js/jquery.terminal.min.js" integrity="sha512-lfkU/Qku0yOVZEYANlw2mOv7fpHFdS1E62UT7vJ55k22OB+xgRNNa6Cdor4Lugl4jhDjX29lJAG12X/OHFe8JQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/2.34.0/css/jquery.terminal.css" integrity="sha512-lT1/Sb6Bu4LaJJoTsxNZnlvt7pjuntBoSqSMJY7MxG5Yl1XgxsXA6jcJinPU0lx5eEsnudBE1ubzHSYR/W8xTw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="myterm"></div>
```

Comment: Yup it's working, sorry idk what was wrong previously .

Comment: the issue was with the cdn's, sometimes they don't work. hosted the js locally with the site everything is working without issue. thanks